# Moment-with-locales and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, momentjs

Good morning,

I'm working on a Angular 1.5-based site that is heavily internationalized, and I'm attempting to integrate MomentJS so our dates can be internationalized as well.

A lot of our code is in TypeScript, and I'm having troubles getting the Moment stuff to work in TypeScript.

Moment is currently at 2.15.2, and there is a moment.d.ts file in the root moment folder, but because I'm internationalizing this I need to use the min/moment-with-locales.js file, and there is no TypeScript definitions file for that.

If I go ahead and use

```
/// <reference path="../../bower_components/moment/moment.d.ts" />
```

it doesn't work because that's a different instance of moment than the moment-with-locales.js I'm using.

This doesn't work either:

```
import moment = require("../../bower_components/moment/min/moment-with-locales");
```

So then I took the moment.d.ts file, copied it into the min/ folder and renamed it moment-with-locales.d.ts, and used that in my TypeScript file, and it appears to be working, but I'm uneasy about that.

So how on earth do I use the moment-with-locales.js file in a TypeScript file?

Am I just doing something wrong, or is it typically this hard using plain JavaScript inside TypeScript?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, in Typescript definition files (`*.d.ts`) are used used in compilation time only and their main purpose is to ensure that your code is in conformity with what is specified in those files.

Definition files do not interfere with their JS counterpart in run time at all, as long as your code pass compilation phase, it should behavior exactly as the JS files are written.

In case you don't have a definition file, as a fast hack, you could simply declare some var or function (please, be aware that this is not a good practice, but, desperate times needs desperate measures).

For instance, suppose you have a library that declares a var called `MySuperComplexJSLibrary`, in Typescript, you could declare/export a var of type `any`. This would allow to use every property and method of this amazing library, without compilation problems.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by creating a new type definition file.
`moment-with-locales.d.ts` I don't think the name matters it just needs to be d.ts with the following definition:

```
declare module 'moment/min/moment-with-locales' {
  import moment from 'moment';
  export = moment;
}
```

As far as I understand, TS will scan and find all d.ts files in source code automatically and will use them to search for module definitions.